# How can I register a custom management command that is tied to the project, not the app?

Tags: python, django

I have a django project whose functionality is split into several interdependent apps. I want to write a custom management command that deletes data from the database and files from the `media` directory for easy testing in the dev environment.

My management command works if I put my `management/commands/custom_command.py` in an app directory, but it won't work it it's in the base project directory. That feels wrong, as it deletes model instances from several apps, not just the one in whose directory it resides.

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) don't seem to cover what to do in this case. What's best practice in my situation?

Comment: Say your project is called website, you'll have the child website directory, where your settings are. Have you tried creating the ```management/commands/custom_command.py``` here? You may possibly have to add "website" to your installed apps in the settings.

Comment: I have actually tried it before, but without adding it to installed apps (it didn't work either). Adding to installed apps doesn't seem to make sense though: 1. I believe apps shouldn't be in the project settings directory, and 2. it's not an app.

Comment: I see your point, but think you're going to have to either take this approach or make a "management app" and put it in there. As far as I can tell, there is no other logical or natural location for this.